# R geom_line not plotting as expected

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using the following code to plot a stacked area graph and I get the expected plot.

```
P <- ggplot(DATA2, aes(x=bucket,y=volume, group=model, fill=model,label=volume)) +  #ggplot initial parameters
  geom_ribbon(position='fill', aes(ymin=0, ymax=1))
```

[image: area plot no lines]

but then when I add lines which are reading the same data source I get misaligned results towards the right side of the graph

```
P + geom_line(position='fill',  aes(group=model, ymax=1))
```

[image: enter area plot with lines]

does anyone know why this may be? Both plots are reading the same data source so I can't figure out what the problem is.

Comment: have you tried changing 1 by Volume?

Comment: Can you make this reproducible? I.e., what's DATA2?

Comment: @NathanWebb here is the CSV https://www.dropbox.com/s/sok588iwscyt14b/porsche%20model%20volumes.csv?dl=0

DATA2 <- read.csv("porsche model volumes.csv", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

Comment: @DerekCorcoran thanks for your reply, please could you be more specific?

Comment: @Tom I have been working in your problem, the first thing I saw is that your x axis is a string and not a numeric parameter which may be affecting the behavior of ggplot, is that intentional? I was transforming it to numeric using gsub, but when I got to bucket 11 its an interval, I chose the second number for that I will put that in my answer

Comment: @Tom please let me know if it did work

Comment: @DerekCorcoran unfortunately it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, if all you wanted to do was draw an outline around the areas, then you could do the same using the colour aesthetic.

```
ggplot(DATA2, aes(x=bucket,y=volume, group=model, fill=model,label=volume)) +
  geom_ribbon(position='fill', aes(ymin=0, ymax=1), colour = "black")
```

Answer (score 0):

I have an answer, I hope it works for you, it looks good but very different from your original graph:

```
library(ggplot2)
DATA2 <- read.csv("C:/Users/corcoranbarriosd/Downloads/porsche model volumes.csv", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

In my experience you want to have X as a numeric variable and you have it as a string, if that is not the case I can Change that, but this will transform your bucket into a numeric vector:

```
bucket.list <- strsplit(unlist(DATA2$bucket), "[^0-9]+")

x=numeric()
for (i in 1:length(bucket.list)) {
     x[i] <-  bucket.list[[i]][2]  
     }

DATA2$bucket <- as.numeric(x)

P <- ggplot(DATA2, aes(x=bucket,y=volume, group=model, fill=model,label=volume)) + 
geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=0, ymax=volume))+ geom_line(aes(group=model, ymax=volume))
```

It gives me the area and the line tracking each other, hope that's what you needed

Comment: ,Many thanks for the reply. this still doesn't give me what I want. The tracking works fine as a normal area graph, but when i add position='fill' to make it look like the graph in my original post the black lines still deviate at the end of the graph. We also now have the added issue of the scale on the X axis being stretched at the end of the graph.

Answer (score 0):

If you switch to using `geom_path` in place of `geom_line`, it all seems to work as expected.  I don't think the ordering of `geom_line` is behaving the same as `geom_ribbon` (and suspect that `geom_line` -- like `geom_area` -- assumes a zero base y value)

```
ggplot(DATA2, aes(x=bucket, y=volume, ymin=0, ymax=1,
                  group=model, fill=model, label=volume)) +
  geom_ribbon(position='fill') +
  geom_path(position='fill')
```

Should give you

[image]

Comment: this is exactly what i required, thanks for putting in the time.